# How can you require a field in an array in CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, couchdb, require

Here is the little JSON file I have. I want the validate_doc_update function to require the address field in the destination array.
{
  "Name": "Someone",
  "secondary_id": "1111",
  "destination": [
  {
    "address": "something"
  }]
}

I have tried this (of course it is not working):

```
function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx){
if(!newDoc.destination.address){
throw({forbidden:'doc.address is required'});
 }
}
```

Is there even a way to require a field in an array? or does couchDB not allow it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that any object in the `destination` array can contain `address` for validation to succeed, you can use the following validation function:

```
function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx) {
  if(newDoc.destination && newDoc.destination.length > 0){
    for(var i = 0; i < newDoc.destination.length; i++){
      if(newDoc.destination[i].address) return;
    }
  }
  throw({forbidden:'doc.address is required'});    
}
```

If you require all objects in the `destination` array to contain `address`, use the following validation function:

```
function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx) {
  if(newDoc.destination && newDoc.destination.length > 0){
    for(var i = 0; i < newDoc.destination.length; i++){
      if(!newDoc.destination[i].address) throw({forbidden:'doc.address is required'});
    }
    return;
  }
  throw({forbidden:'doc.address is required'});
}
```

Comment: The first one was what I was looking for. it worked perfectly. I can't believe I didn't think of such a simple solution. I was overcomplicating things for myself. Thank you very much.